# NodeInitializationAction has no "executableFile" field

Tags: initialization, dataproc

I'm using google.cloud dataprocv1 and trying to create a dataproc cluster. I have to clone a github repo into the cluster, so using Initialization actions, I'm trying to run a bash script which is in Storage bucket of GCP. I'm seeing this error when the code is executed.

```
`Error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/dataproc_creation.py", line 35, in create_cluster
    operation = cluster_client.create_cluster(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1/services/cluster_controller/client.py", line 605, in create_cluster
    request = clusters.CreateClusterRequest(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 598, in __init__
    pb_value = marshal.to_proto(pb_type, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 217, in to_proto
    pb_value = rule.to_proto(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/proto/marshal/rules/message.py", line 36, in to_proto
    return self._descriptor(**value)
ValueError: Protocol message NodeInitializationAction has no "executableFile" field.
Error: exit status 1
```

`

Function for cluster creation:

```
def create_cluster(project_id, region, cluster_name):
    # Create a client with the endpoint set to the desired cluster region.
    cluster_client = dataproc.ClusterControllerClient(
        client_options={"api_endpoint": f"{region}-dataproc.googleapis.com:443"}
    )

    # Create the cluster config.
    cluster = {
        "project_id": project_id,
        "cluster_name": cluster_name,
        "config": {
            "master_config": {"num_instances": 1, "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-2"},
            "worker_config": {"num_instances": 2, "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-2"},
            "initializationActions": [
                {
                    "executableFile": "gs://extracted-bucket/init_actions/git_clone.sh"
                }
            ]
        },
    }

    # Create the cluster.
    operation = cluster_client.create_cluster(
        request={"project_id": project_id, "region": region, "cluster": cluster}
    )
    result = operation.result()

    # Output a success message.
    print(f"Cluster created successfully: {result.cluster_name}")
```

Without the initialization actions, the cluster is getting created. But with the init actions, the error occurred. Tried passing the executableFile as below

```
init_action = {
    'executableFile': 'gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/init_actions/git_clone.py',
    'executionTimeout': '3600s'
}
```

and passing the init_actions in the config

```
cluster_config = {
    "gce_cluster_config": {...},
    "master_config": {...},
    "worker_config": {...},
    "initialization_actions": [init_action]
}
```